# How to scrape fields on eBay using beautifulSoup4 in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csj1RoLTMIA) (which is dated) and adapting this [code](https://github.com/jhnwr/ebay-prices) (which is broken).  Learning a lot about web scraping from this and I've been able to adapt some of it to the changes in backend but not all of them.  For example, I can't figure out how to get the "Sold date".  I understand that it's within here: `<div class="s-item__title--tag">` but I can't seem to scrape it out.

I found this ([Storing data from a tag in Python with BeautifulSoup4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534371/storing-data-from-a-tag-in-python-with-beautifulsoup4)) but was unable to adapt it to my problem.

Below you can see where I stopped, I was unable to scrape the Sold out date after I thought I figured out the pattern.

**Question: Can someone help me adapt my code to pull out the fields of interest?**

The fields I'm interested in are the following:

- Title
- Sold date
- Sold price
- Region purchased (not sold from)

Bonus:

- Link to listing

This is the script I'm using: `ebay_scraper.py`

Usage: `python ebay_scraper.py [search+term+with+spaces+as+plus+signs]`

(e.g., `python ebay_scraper.py darth+vader > output.tsv`)

```py
import sys, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def main():
    searchterm = sys.argv[1]
    url = f"https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw={searchterm}+1&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_Complete=1&_ipg=200&LH_Sold=1&LH_PrefLoc=2&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1"
    print(url, file=sys.stderr)
    soup = get_data(url)
    productlist = parse(soup)
    productsdf = pd.DataFrame(productlist)
    productsdf.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep="\t")

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print('Failed to get data: ', r.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.title.text, file=sys.stderr)
    return soup

def parse(soup):
    productlist = []
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for item in results:
        title = item.find('span', {'role':'heading'}).text
        terms = sys.argv[1].lower().split("+")
        query = title.lower().split(" ")
        n = len(set(terms) & set(query))
        m = len(set(terms))
        if (n/m) >= 0.75:
            if title not in {"Shop on eBay"}:
                sold = item.find('div', {'class': 's-item__title--tag'})     
                if sold is not None:
                    completed = sold.find('span', {'class': 's-item__title--tagblock'})
                    print(completed)
                    if completed is not None:
                        print(completed.find('span', {'class':'POSITIVE'}).text)

                    # products = {
                    # # 'title': item.find('h3', {'class':'s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'}).text,
                    # 'title': item.find('span', {'role':'heading'}).text,
                    # # 'soldprice': float(item.find('span', {'class':'s-item__price'}).text.replace('£','').replace(',','').strip()),
                    # 'solddate': item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__title--tagblock__COMPLETED'}).find('span', {'class':'POSITIVE'}).text,
                    # # 'link': item.find('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})['href']        
                    # }
                    # productlist.append(products)
    return productlist


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your code a bit, mostly for brevity and clarity. I'm not dumping all info to the file, as this is supposed to push you in the right direction.

Anyhow, try this:

```py
import sys

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(query: str) -> None:
    url = f"https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw={query}&_sacat=0"
    print(url, file=sys.stderr)
    df = pd.DataFrame(parse(make_soup(url)), columns=['title', 'price', 'link'])
    df.to_csv("output.csv", sep="\t", index=False)
    print("Done!")


def make_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print('Failed to get data: ', r.status_code)
        sys.exit(1)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


def parse(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list[list[str]]:
    result = []
    items = soup.select(".srp-main--isLarge .srp-grid .s-item")
    for item in items:
        title = item.select_one(".s-item__title").getText(strip=True)
        price = item.select_one(".s-item__price").getText(strip=True)
        link = item.select_one(".s-item__link")['href']
        result.append([title, price, link])
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

This should ouput a `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Testing this out now.  I'm not sure if this is for sold items and looks like it might be for current listings.